# Keep duplicate fields in a UNION ALL query with a new field listing the frequency duplicates and non-duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, union

I have been trying to make a SQL query in Access that uses UNION to extract related rows and makes a new field listing the count of the duplicates vs. non-duplicates. So far all I can seem to do is either list the duplicates with a count or keep all duplicates with the counter only show 1 even when a duplicate. Can anybody please help me fix this code to aggregate the data properly?

This was my last effort.

```
SELECT Type, Season, Count(Type) As TypeDups
FROM (
  SELECT Type, Season, TypeDups FROM Report11_12
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Type, Season, TypeDups FROM Report12_13
  UNION ALL
) AS  Duplicates
GROUP BY Type, Season
ORDER BY Type;
```

| Type | Season | TypeDups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 19 | 2 |
| A | 20 | 2 |
| B | 20 | 1 |
| C | 18 | 1 |

All help is truly appreciated

Laurence

Comment: Please provide a test case, with tables, some data and the output you expect, given that data.  The tables / data only need to contain just the columns of interest / required, not every column.

Comment: Most important: Please define what you mean by `duplicate`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you didn't want to `GROUP BY TypeDups`.

```
SELECT Type, Season, Count(Type) As TypeDups
  FROM (
         SELECT Type, Season FROM Report11_12
          UNION ALL
         SELECT Type, Season FROM Report12_13
       ) AS  Duplicates
 GROUP BY Type, Season
 ORDER BY Type
;
```

To return the original rows with count detail over all like rows, we would normally use window functions.  MS Access probably doesn't support this.

Instead, we can try the following, to `JOIN` that detail to the original rows:

```
SELECT xrows.Type, xrows.Season, Duplicates.TypeDups
  FROM (
         SELECT Type, Season FROM Report11_12
          UNION ALL
         SELECT Type, Season FROM Report12_13
       ) AS  xrows
  JOIN (
         SELECT Type, Season, Count(Type) As TypeDups
           FROM (
                  SELECT Type, Season FROM Report11_12
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT Type, Season FROM Report12_13
                ) AS  Duplicates
          GROUP BY Type, Season
       ) AS  Duplicates
    ON xrows.Type   = Duplicates.Type
   AND xrows.Season = Duplicates.Season
 ORDER BY xrows.Type
;
```

Here's a working example, with window functions and the non-window function / `JOIN` approach:

[Working test case with SQL Server, not Access, to show the logic](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=beb37da3fab91df72b73daca3ecc9449)

Example result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jon, Yeah I was trying to add a table to show what I need in a clear but I was clearly doing something wrong as the formatting was weird even though the table looked like it was working.... The above does list the counts correctly (i.e. 1 vs. 2) but the duplicates have been aggreagated into one row.

Comment: So you want the original rows, with the combined counts with each row?  That can be done with window functions, which MS Access probably doesn't support.  But we should still be able to do this by `JOIN`ing in that detail.  I'll attempt to update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jon I really appreciate it. I am getting a syntax error in the FROM clause in MS Access. I'm currently trialling a few things to see if I can fix but have not managed it yet

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original rows with a duplicate count, then a correlated subquery might be a simple solution:

```
SELECT R.*,
       ( (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Report11_12 R1
          WHERE R1.Type = R.Type AND R1.Season = R.Season
         ) +
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Report12_13 R1
          WHERE R1.Type = R.Type AND R1.Season = R.Season
         )
       ) As TypeDups
FROM (SELECT Type, Season, TypeDups FROM Report11_12
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Type, Season, TypeDups FROM Report12_13
     ) As R;
```

Note:  It is usually a bad practice to have multiple tables with the same columns.  You might consider having a single `Reports` table with an additional column to distinguish which report.